# Conditional statement (given)

Tags: c++

Is there a way to write the following statement in one condition statement?

a and b are not equal to five at the same time. (a can be five and b can be five, but a AND b cannot be five)

Comment: OH -- completely misread. //fail

Comment: if ( a != 5 || b != 5 )

Comment: Is both not equal to 5 allowed?

Answer (score 3):

As chris pointed out, what you're looking for is logical XOR, which is equivalent to logical not equals `!=`:

```
if ((x == 5) != (y == 5))
```

I would be tempted to write it using bitwise XOR though as it would be much more readable and immediately recognizable as XOR:

```
if (x == 5 ^ y == 5)
```

Of note though is that bitwise operators do not short circuit. It doesn't matter with XOR since both operands have to be evaluated anyway, but it can be important to know with the other operations.

(*Preachy warning*: In almost all situations, don't use bitwise operators in boolean context. Some of the operators have slightly different semantics, and as they don't short circuit there can be some rather odd gotcha's.)

Comment: There is a logical XOR. It's written as !=.

Comment: @chris Yes, `x != y` implies `x ^ y`. It does not generalize to expressions for x and y well though. How can you compactly express with `!=` the intended logic here? I feel like I'm missing something obvious now :).

Comment: It's not too great at being recognizable as XOR, but it would be `(x == 5) != (y == 5)`.

Comment: @chris Ah, it's not nearly as gross as I was thinking. I was trying to involve an additional `(x == 5 || y == 5)` like `(x == 5 || y == 5) && ((x == 5) != (y == 5))`. I see now that `(x == 5 || y == 5)` implies the previous. I've updated my answer to make note of !=.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a!=b && (a==5 || b==5))
{
}
```

and thanks @chris

Comment: I would find `a != b` a lot more understandable than `a+b != 10`. Plus the latter can overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((a == 5 && b != 5) || (a != 5 && b == 5))
{
  //expr
}
```